# Table caption width

Tags: html, caption

I have been given an existing table layout (for tabular data) with the task of making it as accessible as possible.

I added a caption tag to each table within the layout and I realized the caption width is not consistent across different browsers. After a bit of trial and error with CSS, I managed to get it right on all the browsers I need to support aside from Firefox (very last release) where the tables are larger than their own captions (with same width declared in the CSS)

I have googled a bit and this seems to be a known issue.

Any standard solution/suggestion for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "accessible". is it for the visually impaired? do you mean something else?

Comment: Basically it should be used by screen readers. I went through some "accessibility guide" for tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirko

Keep in mind that captions don't HAVE to be visible and they still will be accesible, for instance if you hide them (display:none OR visibility:hidden), the width won't matter, as they won't be "seen" in the page, however a screen reader will still pick them up.